# Strange behaviour with Java library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hyperlink

I'm trying to set up my eclipse java projects on a new machine and have (predictably - migration with eclipse has never 'just worked' for me) encountered numerous problems.

One example is with my maths library - when trying to import from that library and run a program I've had the following error message

> The project: tmath which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

Looking at my classpath, the library is referenced like this:

`<classpathentry kind="src" path="/tmath"/>`

this is linking from a very basic hello world program

I then tried making a new project (tmaths2) and copied the source over.
That worked but the strange thing is, I can spot *nothing* to differentiate the contents of 'tmath' and 'tmath2' folders. The '.project' and '.classpath' files are identical (save for the addition of the '2'). One telling symptom is that there are no .class files in the 'tmath' project so something, somewhere (possibly referenced outside of my project file) is telling eclipse not to build my 'tmath' library. 
  Can anybody shed any light on what could be causing this problem?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sometimes that happens with eclipse..while working with eclipse sometimes it keeps giving you some error and moving complete project to a new project works like a charm!

Comment: So eclipse has to be storing something somewhere. It's really annoying - puts me off doing Java to be honest.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that something in .metadata is corrupt. And that's all inscrutable binary blobs. Great - I don't think I'll be fixing that. Time to give intellij another go :(

Comment: Yeah you may try with some other IDE!

Comment: In the end I got it working in eclipse by nuking the .metadata folder and re-importing my projects.  It all seems pretty fragile and cludgy so yes, I'm going to give another IDE a proper go.